# Add condition to show a div

Tags: woocommerce

I'm searching a way to show a message/notice only for logged-in users if the user email address field in his account is empty. I'm using Woocommerce.

I was thinking that this function will works fine but no :-/ Any help is appreciate. Thanks in advance

```html
function bdev_validate_registration_email( $errors, $email ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_email'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_email'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'billing_email_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Email is required!', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
    return $errors;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_errors', 'bdev_validate_registration_email', 10, 2 );
```